# Get a part of XML using XSLT transformation

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to the XSL transformations. Where i am trying to extract a part of XML using XSLT.

The Source XML

```
<tree>
    <trunk>
        <branch>
            <leaves></leaves>
            <flowers></flowers>
            <fruits></fruits>
        </branch>
    </trunk>
</tree>
```

and i am expecting the following XML as output

```
<root>    
    <branch>
        <leaves></leaves>
        <flowers></flowers>
        <fruits></fruits>
    </branch>
</root>
```

Please provide the transformation, i have been doing some random stuff for long time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the following

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="1.0" >

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:element name="root">
        <xsl:for-each  select="//branch">
            <xsl:element name="branch">
                <xsl:for-each select="*">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 5):

```
  <xsl:template match="/tree/trunk/branch">
    <root>
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>
```